# How to dispose of idle PUBSUB Redis connections

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I was recently doing some investigation into some issues I'm facing on my Redis clusters, and saw that I have many connections that are sticking around, despite being idle indefinitely after some period of time.

After some investigation, I found that I have these two settings on my cluster:

```
timeout 300
tcp-keepalive 0
```

The stale connections that aren't going away are PUB/SUB client connections (StackExchange.Redis clients, in fact, but that's beside the point), so they do not respect the timeout configuration. As such, the tcp-keepalive seems to be the only other configuration that can ensure these connections get cleaned up over time.

So I applied this setting to all the nodes:

```
redis-trib.rb call 127.0.0.1:6001 config set tcp-keepalive 300
```

At this point I went home, and I came back the next morning, assuming the stale connections would have been disposed of properly. Sadly, I was greeted by all the same connections.

My question is: Is there any way from the Redis server side to dispose of these connections gracefully after they've been established? Is it expected that applying the tcp-keepalive configuration after the connections are established and old that they will not be disposed of?

The only solution I've found besides restarting the Redis servers are to do a bit of scripting and use the [CLIENT KILL](https://redis.io/commands/client-kill) command, which is doable, but I was hoping for something configuration based to handle this.

Thanks in advance for any insight here!

Comment: yes, either the client application should close the pub-sub connections, or you can use the "client kill type pubsub" command

Comment: CLIENT KILL type pubsub kills *all* pubsub connections - I was looking for a way to only kill the ones that are stale and not still active. My solution was to write a quick script to parse the CLIENT LIST output and look for idle times greater than X, and call CLIENT KILL on them, as opposed to CLIENT KILL type pubsub which wholesale kills all pubsub connections.

Comment: How can you be sure that if time is greater than X, the connection is stale? Pubsub connections are meant to be long lasting , so that's why they are unaffected by the timeout parameter.

Comment: Normally all active clients in all languages reestablish connection when the connection is killed. So killing all pubsub connections is the easy way which has the desired effect(almost)